# Which MS Office Applications allow ActiveX controls to be embedded in their documents?

Tags: vba, controls, ms-office, activex

I'm testing some code that enumerates the ActiveX controls in Office documents, but some Office applications make adding ActiveX controls easier than others. I'm specifically talking about ActiveX controls on the document, as opposed to ActiveX controls on UserForms.

For example, from the Developer Tab, I can add a CommandButton ActiveX control to **Excel** Worksheets (but not to Chartsheets) and **Word** Documents.

I can also add ActiveX controls to **PowerPoint** Slides and Masters, and to **Visio** Pages and Masters.

**Access** does have controls on Reports and Forms, but as far as I can tell, they're not always ActiveX controls, depending on the version of Access.

Are there any places that I've missed, what about **Project** and **Publisher**?

Are there any prior Office application versions in which ActiveX controls were available, but aren't any longer? And likewise, are there any Office application versions where controls only became available later than in other applications?

Are there any subtleties to the implementation and support for ActiveX controls across Office applications?

Bonus Points for details of any other application that supports VBA and ActiveX controls, other than **AutoCAD**.

Here's what I know so far:

```
+=================+==============================+
| Application     | ActiveX Container            |
+=================+==============================+
| Word            | Document (inline shapes)     |
|                 | Document (shapes)            |
+-----------------+------------------------------+
| Excel           | Worksheets                   |
+-----------------+------------------------------+
| PowerPoint      | Slides                       |
|                 | Masters                      |
+-----------------+------------------------------+
| Visio           | Pages                        |
|                 | Masters                      |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Excel and Visio seem to both allow controls to be grouped.